# Setting nomodeset to fix blank screen on boot breaks browser rendering

Tags: 12.04, graphics, video, display, nomodeset

I have upgraded my wifes netbook (Novatech X10) from 10.04 to 12.04 and hit the same problem I had with 11.04 and 11.10 with the blank screen on boot. I can fix this by adding the `nomodeset` option to grub but this seems to make the graphics experience slightly worse (it does not seem as clear) also the web browsers Firefox/Chrome do not render the screen width correctly.

Currently I am working around it by not setting nomodeset` and telling my wife to close the lid after boot and reopen it (the screen then works) but she is complaining about this and wishing "I had not messed with it"

Any ideas at all?

`lspci` shows the controller as intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller" I have not installed any other drivers, and the additional drivers search did not find any.

Thanks Andi

Comment: please add details of your graphics card (`lspci | grep VGA`) - as well as any graphics drivers you might have installed through the Additional Drivers window.  Thanks!

Comment: Hiya, Not sure if my last update worked but it is "intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller" I have not installed any other drivers, and the additional drivers search did not find any.

Comment: if you have intel graphics, you could/should try `i915.modeset=0` or `i915.modeset=1` instead of `nomodeset`.  Give this a try.  Remember - edit your original question with any useful info such as your graphics comment above.  thanks.

Comment: Hiya, I tried the two settings, and they seemed to have the same effect as setting nomodeset or not setting it. The =0 seemed to stretc the screen in the same way as setting nomodeset and the =1 had the same issue with the blank screen. Thankd for your help so far!

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in ~2 years. Question is 5+ years old with no answers but likely resolved by now with new OS or different hardware altogether.  12.04 is EOL now. VTC as `not reproducible`